# TextBox in Matlab Plot

Tags: matlab

Please help me here. I am trying to include a small textbox with boundaries in  matlab plot, that says certain important things about the plot. I did come across this link,

http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154660

But I want to know if there's any other inbuilt plot function that can do this directly. I am really sorry, if this question is rudimentary, But I will be thankful for your help.

Moreover, am not actually clear what this link is exactly saying. How will the mtext place the textbox in plot? How do I actually code it? These are my confusions. Please help me here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html).

For example, `annotation('textbox',[x y w h])` creates an editable text box annotation with its lower left corner at the point `x,y`, a width `w`, and a height `h`, specified in normalized figure units. Specify `x`, `y`, `w`, and `h` in a single vector.

Here a demonstration with some bells and whistles...

```
x=0:0.1:10;
var=1.85;
y=x.^(var);
plot(x,y);

annotation('textbox',...
    [0.15 0.65 0.3 0.15],...
    'String',{'plotting y=x^{var} ,',['with var =' num2str(var)]},...
    'FontSize',14,...
    'FontName','Arial',...
    'LineStyle','--',...
    'EdgeColor',[1 1 0],...
    'LineWidth',2,...
    'BackgroundColor',[0.9  0.9 0.9],...
    'Color',[0.84 0.16 0]);
```

[image]

For a full list of the annotation textbox properties is found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotationtextboxproperties.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient description and help. can I include variables here? to display their values?

Comment: it is throwing error saying unknown argument. could you please help?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by include a variable. Is that variable a number, a matrix, a string, a more elaborate class like a cell or struct? have you copied the code bit in the answer? does it still gives an error?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. by variable, I mean I have a int value to be included in the text box. is it possible? should I use 2 annotations for that?

Comment: I resolved the error. I entered the string with small s. sorry for bothering. I will be really glad if you can help me with this.

Comment: use `num2str` to make a string out of a numeric variable. See my edited answer that uses it and many other features...

Comment: Thank you for detailed example. I had to replace `['with var =' num2str(var)]` with `['with var =' + num2str(var)]`

Answer (score -1):

```
alldatacursors = findall(gcf,'type','hggroup')
set(alldatacursors,'FontSize',11)
set(alldatacursors,'FontName','Times')
set(alldatacursors,'BackgroundColor','w');
```

Comment: What is this for? Is this supposed to be an answer to the question?

Comment: Probably suppose to be here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600101/customizing-data-cursor-marker-matlab/47037407#47037407