# Customizing Data Cursor marker Matlab

Tags: matlab, cursor

Is there any possibility to change marker form and size for data cursor in Matlab? I mean it is black and square by default. I would like to change it to blue and circle, for example.
I've found only how to customize text of data tips.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - marker options are included in the properties of the undocumented `graphics.datatip` object class.

These objects are accessible as hidden properties of the `graphics.datacursormanager` objects accessible through the documented `datacursormode` function. The `.DataCursors` property contains an array of these objects for each Data Cursor in the figure and `.CurrentDataCursor` property contains the object for the current one.

To take your example, to change the marker for the current Data Cursor of the current figure to a blue circle, you can do as follows:

```matlab
dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf);
set(dcm_obj.CurrentDataCursor, 'Marker','o', 'MarkerFaceColor','b');
```

More detailed information about the undocumented functionality can be found at http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps..... For white background and classic look....

- alldatacursors = findall(gcf,'type','hggroup')
- set(alldatacursors,'FontSize',11)
- set(alldatacursors,'FontName','Times')
- set(alldatacursors,'BackgroundColor','w');

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible by set `Pointer` property of `figure` to `custom` and then set the value for  `PointerShapeCData` as per your choice but you can't change to RGB color format. Because `PointerShapeCData` property accept value 1 and 2. value 1 means black and 2 means white.

for example :

```
a = zeros(16,16);   % create matrix with size of 16 X 16 with value zero
a(:,:) = 1;         % assign all element value of matrix a to 1.
figure('Pointer','custom ','PointerShapeCData',a); 

% change some element value of a variable as 2 for change black to white.

a(:,1) = 2;         
 a(:,3) = 2;
 a(:,7) = 2;
 figure('Pointer','custom ','PointerShapeCData',a);
```

Comment: Could you please write some code to demonstrate it?

Comment: The question is about *[data cursors](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html)*. The `Pointer` property affects the *mouse cursor* displayed when the pointer is hovering over the figure.